# Forcing http to https in htaccess, always redirect to homepage

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-7

I cannot redirect `http://example.com/test` to `https://example.com/test`. It will always get redirect to the homepage. I did a search in Google for a couple of hours with no solution. Below is my `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]
  RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]
    RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
    RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

    <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
      Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

I did somehow manage to achieve what I want, by commenting out:

```
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
# RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But it causes another problem for my site. I get 404 error and it breaks my site when I visit the back end system. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```

Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is in the wrong place. This should go at the very start of the file, not at the end. By placing this redirect after the front controller (the bit of code you commented out) it will indeed trigger a redirect to `index.php`.

Also, this should be a permanent (301) redirect (once you have confirmed it is working OK). You will also need the `L` flag and there is no need to capture the `RewriteRule` pattern if you are using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable. So, this should be written like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```

In fact, both these directives should go at the start of the file. And the first `RewriteRule` should redirect to `https`, not `http`, otherwise you'll get an additional (unnecessary) redirect.

Comment: It didn't redirect the site to https. now all the css, js, and img is failed to load with status 404.

Comment: Failing CSS, JS and images are indicative of relative URLs in the client-side HTML. However, there's no obvious reason why this wouldn't redirect if it redirected before when you commented out the _front controller_? How is the SSL managed? I've updated my answer - note that your canonical www to non-www redirect should also go at the start of the file. Post your updated `.htaccess` file to your question.

Comment: i manage to solved this by using another drupal module (seckit). Thanks for your help.